# Reference a library which has only NuGet packages installed

Tags: c#, reference, nuget

Here is an interesting question.

I tried to install NuGet packages to a class library project and referencing it from different projects. However, after rebuilding it seems these different projects couldn't know the packages.

Isn't referencing to a project which has only NuGet packages installed supported?

Comment: Are these "sdk-based" projects - so .NET 5+ / .NET Core / .NET Standard class libraries or classic csproj with e.g. packages.config files? Transitive packages are supported by default for these newer project types.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static class with a static method and in that method reference logic from each of the packages that you want to be included, just create an instance of a class and call `ToString()` on it. That way they are less likely to be optimised out of the build process.

The real question is why would you do this? Just make your own NuGet Package if you just want to groups them together. A NuGet Package *can* be empty, in the definition file just specify the dependencies.